# Reading file inside Spring boot fat jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

We have a spring boot application which has a legacy jar api that we use that needs to load properties by using InputFileStream. We wrapped the legacy jar in our spring boot fat jar and the properties files are under BOOT-INF/classes folder. I could see spring loading all the relevant properties but when I pass the properties file name to the legacy jar it could not read the properties file as its inside the jar and is not under physical path. In this scenario how do we pass the properties file to the legacy jar?

Please note we cannot change the legacy jar.

Comment: What does the API in the legacy jar let you pass into it? Can you pass an InputStream or does it only take a String that it interprets as a file system path?

Comment: Yes the legacy jar only allows me to pass a String which is the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't, because the properties "file" is not a file, it's a resource in a jar file, which is compressed (it's actually a .zip file).

AFAIK, the only way to make this work is to extract the file from the jar, and put it on your server in a well-known location. Then at runtime open that file with an FileInputStream and pass it to the legacy method.

Comment: We wanted to deploy the application as one fat jar and run it as standalone. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The only solution that I can think of is to get the file at runtime, as an InputStream, via getResourceAsStream, write it out to a file (as a temp file?), then open it with a FileInputStream

Comment: Let me try this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can, using [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html). You just have to emulate a filesystem on the folder you need to get the file from. For example if you wanted to get `file.properties`, which is under `src/main/resources` you could do something like this:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(this.getClass().getResource("").toURI(), Collections.emptyMap());
String pathToMyFile = fs.getPath("file.properties").toString();
yourLegacyClassThatNeedsAndAbsoluteFilePath.execute(pathToMyFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have faced this issue recently. I have a file I put in the resource file, let's call it `path` and I was not able to read it. @madoke has given one of the solutions using FileSystem. This is another one, here we are assuming we are in a container, and if not, we use the Java 8 features.

```
@Component 
@Log4j2
public class DataInitializer implements 
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

private YourRepo yourRepo; // this is your DataSource Repo

@Value(“${path.to.file}”). // the path to file MUST start with a forward slash: /iaka/myfile.csv
private String path;

public DataInitializer(YourRepo yourRepo) {
    this.yourRepo = yourRepo;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    try {
        persistInputData();
        log.info("Completed loading data");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error in reading / parsing CSV", e);
    }
}

private void persistInputData() throws IOException {
    log.info("The path to Customers: "+ path);
    Stream<String> lines;
    InputStream inputStream = DataInitializer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    if (inputStream != null) { // this means you are inside a fat-jar / container
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        lines = bufferedReader.lines();
    } else {
        URL resource = this.getClass().getResource(path);
        String path = resource.getPath();
        lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path));
    }

    List<SnapCsvInput> inputs = lines.map(s -> s.split(","))
                                     .skip(1) //the column names
                                     .map(SnapCsvInput::new)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    inputs.forEach(i->log.info(i.toString()));
    yourRepo.saveAll(inputs);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @moldovean's solution, you just need to call 'getResourceAsStream(path)' and continue with returned InputStream. Be aware that the 'path' is based on ClassPath. For example:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your-file.csv");
```

In root of your class path, there is a file named 'your-file.csv' that you want to read.