# Java read file from resources folder

Tags: java

I have a project named `myProjectModule` It has following structure:

```
myProjectModule/
  -src/
    -com/foo/bar/TestDataProvider.java
    -main/resources/testfile.json
```

So the two files have path:

```
src/test/com/foo/bar/TestDataProvider.java
src/main/resources/testfile.json
```

I want to read testfile.json in TestDataProvider.java.

I've used

```
        URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testfile.json");
        System.out.println(res);

        File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
        String filename = file.getAbsolutePath()
        final JsonNode root = mapper.readValue(new File(filename), JsonNode.class);
```

I see `null` being returned from `URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testfile.json");`

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Did you forget a "test" between "src" and "com" in the first path?

Comment: Assuming that you meant src/test/com/foo/bar/TestDataProvider.java, is the resource testfile.json in the same module than the test class or are you trying to access the resource of another module?

Comment: If this is a spring boot fat jar then see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983100/reading-file-inside-spring-boot-fat-jar

Comment: It is in the same module. No, I do not have a test in betwen src and com. I thought that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your in the maven project,your code in:src/ is not in classpath,you should run it in src/main/java/